# Trigger mousewheel event infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousewheel

I want my `mousewheel` event to trigger every time I scroll my mouse up. Can you  help me? Because it only fires once. Please see my code below.

```
   $('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        $("#room").trigger("click");
      foo = true;
      mousewheel = true;
    }
    else{
        alert('down');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *mousewheel* event was non-standard and now depreciated, use the vanilla [*wheel* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) instead,

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY / 120 > 0) {
        $("#room").trigger("click");
        foo = true;
        mousewheel = true;
    } else {
        alert('down');
    }
});
```

See [**the code in the compatibility section**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser) if you need to support legacy

---

Example proving it fires multiple times (use console)

```
document.body.addEventListener('wheel', console.dir.bind(console));
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! I got it working on the console but the event itself doesn't occur infinitely. Can you help me check it again? Again, thanks!